# Changing as "Factor" to time

Tags: r

How can I transform  a value from `Factor` to `time` ? I've tried using lubridate package but had no success.

I have a dataframe with a column "time" with 08:00:00 like values. Then used

```
phsb1 <- phsb %>%
   dplyr::mutate(time = lubridate::hm(time))
```

with resulted in a class with 6 slots
data year month day hour and minutes

Any help to be able to obtain 08:00 like values would be very much appreciated.
Further more information or advice regarding how to handle "time" would be fantastic. I've found a lot about "dates" but almost nothing related to "time".

Comment: First use as.character before trying to convert to a date/time object.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to convert a column containing data in `H:M:S' format to`H:M` format in character.

**Option #1**: Simply get `substring` containing part of `hour` and `min` using `sub` as:

```
library(dplyr)
phsb1 <- phsb %>%
       mutate(time = sub("(\\d{2}:\\d{2}):\\d{2}","\\1", as.character(time)))
```

**Option #2**: Use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` as.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
phsb1 <- phsb %>%
       mutate(time = format(parse_date_time(as.character(time), "HMS"), format = "%H:%M"))

#Example
format(parse_date_time("08:05:00", "HMS"), format = "%H:%M")
#"08:05"
```

Comment: Dave2e and MKR many thanks for your time! I tried both dplyr::mutate(time = lubridate::hms(time)) and dplyr::mutate(time = lubridate::hms(as.character(time))) and I still get the same result i.e. $ time Formal Class "period" [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots Data,  year, month,  day, hour , minute

Comment: Thank you MKR no the problem is not solved yet. I just posted a new comment. thanks

Comment: @Virgilio No worries. Please share few samples from output you are getting. and also what do you expect?

Comment: @Virgilio In case you are looking for numeric value of `Time` then you can try `time_length()` which will give you time in seconds. May be `time_length(time, unit = "hour")` is what you are looking for.

Comment: MKR Many thanks for your time and attention. I should  I've gave more details about my issue. As end product I need a graph showing change in pH level through a day (for several days) y axis  pH and x axis the 24h of a day.  data.frame': 21483 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ time     : Factor w/ 24 levels "00:00","01:00",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 $ ph       : num  6.28 6.5 6.55 6.64 6.67 6.62 6.77 6.81 6.91 6.8 ... I can plot the graph using ggplot2 however I want to be able to have the x axis of the graph in the form of hours i.e. 00:00, 01:00, etc.

Comment: @Virgilio Sorry. Now, I have understood your expectations. Let me update my answer.